# Foreigner wishes to open a US bank account

Tags: united-states, savings, bank-account

My mother-in-law has had bank accounts in the US for many years.  She has a social security number but she is too frail to travel here. My wife has Power of Atty. giving her specific powers to open a bank account for her mother.   Given this situation, can my mother (through my wife's POA) open another bank account at another bank without coming here?

Comment: You'll probably need to ask in the bank you want an account at.